# Pourquoi prononce-t-on « second » comme \sə.ɡɔ̃\ avec la consonne voisée \g\ plutot que la consonne sourde \k\?

Tags: prononciation

[wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/second) - second \sə.ɡɔ̃\ ordinal

En effet, j'ai entendu cette prononciation de « c dur » comme \g\ moi-même et pas seulement avec le mot « second ». Je soupçonne c'est un cas de [lénition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9nition). Y a-t-il autre mots importants avec telle prononciation voisée d'une « c dur » ?

Il me semble généralement que « c dur » est prononce un peu plus voisée que « q ».

Je m'excuse à l'avance pour mon français.

Comment: La question devrait plutôt être: *pourquoi écrit-on second avec un C et pas un G ?* et la réponse est probablement pour des raisons étymologiques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu donnes la réponse (lénition) dans ta question.  La prononciation avec le son /g/ et non /k/ est ancienne.  Elle est attestée dès le Moyen-Age.

J'ajouterais qu'un des facteurs qui bloque certainement une prononciation en /k/ conforme à l'orthographe, c'est l'homophonie qui en résulterait entre *second* et *ce con*.  Ce serait une source d'ambiguïté plaisante, *Il est arrivé second* pouvant être interprété en *Il est arrivé, ce con*.